# Emacs dired buffer reuse when moving to previous directory

Tags: emacs, dired

I am following [this wiki suggestion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredReuseDirectoryBuffer#toc2) to set up Emacs so that, i can move forward and backwards in dired mode without creating new buffers.

Using the `a` key together with the `(put 'dired-find-alternate-file 'disabled nil)` setting allows me to move into directories without new buffers.

But the hook for the `^` key mentioned in the wiki is not working for me. Going to previous directory with `^` still opens new buffers.

Here are the settings I am using in my `.emacs.d/init.el`

```
; dired settings
(require 'dired-x)
(setq dired-omit-files "^\\.?#\\|^\\.$\\|^\\.\\.$\\|^\\.")
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda ()
                             (dired-omit-mode 1)))
(setq dired-listing-switches "-aBhl --group-directories-first")
(put 'dired-find-alternate-file 'disabled nil)
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
  (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "^")
    (lambda () (interactive) (find-alternate-file "..")))))
```

Comment: Your code for the keyboard shortcut looks good -- if it's opening a new buffer, your keyboard shortcut is probably not being recognized for some reason -- if you do a `C-h k ^` you'll probably see that the default function `dired-up-directory` is still being called.  Are the any error messages?  I get errors when trying to load `dired-x` -- `Key sequence * O starts with non-prefix key *`

Comment: I believe this is the case. The `define-key` keyboard shortcut is not getting recognized for some reason. If i type `M-x find-alternate-file` and then `..` it goes back without creating new buffer. Also `C-h k ^` shows that `^` is bound to `dired-up-directory`. I do not get any errors though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/DiredPlus).  Use `C-M-R` to toggle whether to reuse Dired buffers.  Put this in your init file if you want to reuse by default:

```
 (diredp-make-find-file-keys-reuse-dirs)
```

This also takes care of `^`.  In sum, no need to code anything - just load **Dired+**.

Comment: I have installed dired+ over the package manager. It seems that the version of dired+ that gets installed doesnt have this function. Could i be getting outdated versions from the package archives? I have added marmalade to my `package-archives` list

Comment: @z33m -- Dunno what the problem could be. That function has been in `dired+.el` since 2010/01/21, as the Change Log in the file shows. Visit the file and see if you don't find that function. Does `C-h f` for that function name really tell you it is not defined, after you have loaded `dired+.el`? Note that this function is not a *command* -- you cannot invoke it using `M-x`. But you can evaluate the sexp I wrote using `M-:` (or using `C-x C-e` on it in, say, `*scratch*` or your init file).

Comment: yes i was trying to run it with `M-x`. i've added this command to my `init.el` and its working now. Thanks!